# How to get product id and display its details in django

Tags: python, django

I followed a YouTube tutorial to make e-commerce site and now I'm trying to learn by adding new features to it. I am able to populate different products from the model.

I want to display the details of the clicked product on a different page.
this is what i have done so far.

Thanks

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
digital=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=False,blank=False)
image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
description=models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
def store(request):
    data=cartData(request)
    cartItems=data['cartItems']
    order=data['order']
    items=data['items']   
    products=Product.objects.all()
    context={'products':products,'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request,"foodapp/home.html",context)

def detail(request):
    products=Product.objects.get(id=product.id)
    context={'products':products}

    return render(request,"foodapp/detail.html",context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
path('',views.store,name='store'),
path('cart/',views.cart,name='cart'),
path('checkout/',views.checkout,name='checkout'),
path('update_item/',views.updateItem,name='update_item'),
path('signup/',views.SignUp.as_view(),name='signup'),
path('logout/',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(next_page='login'),name='logout'),
path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='foodapp/login.html'),
                                                                name='login'),
path('process_order/',views.processOrder,name='process_order'),
path('detail/',views.detail,name='detail'),
```

home.html

```
    {% for product in products %}   
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="box-element product">
    <img  class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="">
    <hr>
    <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Type:</h6>
    <button  data-product="{{ product.id }}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add- 
     btn update-cart">
    <a href="#"> Add to Cart</a></button>&nbsp;

    <button data-product="{{ product.id }}"  class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <a href="{% url 'detail' %}">View</a>

    </button>
    
    <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right;">{{product.price}}
    </h4>
    
    </div> 
        
   </div>
```

details.html

```
    {% for product in products %}   
    <div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="box-element product">
    <img  class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}" alt="">
    <hr>
    <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
    <hr>
    <h6>Type:</h6>
    <button  data-product="{{ product.id }}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add- 
     btn update-cart">
    <a href="#"> Add to Cart</a></button>&nbsp;

    <button data-product="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <a href="{% url 'detail' %}">View</a>

    </button>
    
    <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right;">{{product.price}}
    </h4>
    
    </div> 
        
    
        
    
     
  

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

utiils.py

```
def cartData(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user = request.user
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=user, complete=False)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    cartItems = order.get_cart_items
else:
    cookieData = cookieCart(request)
    cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
    order = cookieData['order']
    items = cookieData['items']

return {'cartItems':cartItems ,'order':order, 'items':items}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to get single `Product` instance and pass it as a context in the template.

urls.py

```
path('<int:id>/detail/',views.detail,name='detail'),
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, id):
    product=Product.objects.get(id=id)
    context={'product':product}

    return render(request,"foodapp/detail.html",context)
```

And your detail url should be something like this.

```
{% for product in products %}   
    ......

    <button data-product="{{ product.id }}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <a href="{% url 'detail' product.id %}">View</a>

    </button>
```

You might want to take a look at the Django generic [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) also which will make this thing litter easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the small thing that you have to do:

```
Urls.py
path('detail/<int:pk>', views.detail,name='detail')

Views.py
 def detail(request, pk): 
   products=Product.objects.get(id=pk) 
   context={'products':products}
   return  render(request,"foodapp/detail.html",

 Template
   <a href="{% url 'detail' product.id %}">View</a>
```